# java File sorting order in windows and linux difference

Tags: java, windows, linux, sorting

I have a folder in windows/Linux which has below files

```
test_1a.play
test_1AA.play
test_1aaa.play
test-_1AAAA.play
```

I am reading files and and storing it But windows and linux gives different order. As my application runs in both platform I need consistent order(Linux order). Any suggestion for fixing this.

```
File root = new File( path );
File[] list = root.listFiles();
list<File> listofFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
.....
for ( File f : list ) {


...
read and store file in listofFiles
...
}
Collections.sort(listofFiles);
```

**Windows gives me below order**

```
test-_1AAAA.play
test_1a.play
test_1AA.play
test_1aaa.play
```

**Linux gives me below order**

```
test-_1AAAA.play
test_1AA.play
test_1a.play
test_1aaa.play
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix the problem, but it's more likely to be the type of JVM you are using than the platform. Linux installations generally use OpenJVM, whereas Windows is usually the Sun JVM. You could try installing the Sun JVM on the Linux platform and see if the results change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to implement your own `Comparator<File>` since the `File.compareTo` uses the "systems" order.

I think (not checked) that Linux uses the "standard" order by file name (case sensitive) so an example implementation could look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    files.add(new File("test_1a.play"));
    files.add(new File("test_1AA.play"));
    files.add(new File("test_1aaa.play"));
    files.add(new File("test-_1AAAA.play"));

    Collections.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
            String p1 = o1.getAbsolutePath();
            String p2 = o2.getAbsolutePath();
            return p1.compareTo(p2);
        }
    });

    System.out.println(files);
}
```

Outputs:

```
[test-_1AAAA.play, test_1AA.play, test_1a.play, test_1aaa.play]
```

Comment: I'd use `getName` and not `getAbsolutePath`, but 6 = 2 * 3 in any case.

Comment: @goldilocks: `File.getName` returns the "last" name of the file path. Sorting files in different directories would end up "together", that just doesn't make sense. `File.getAbsolutePath` get the whole path (including the last name), not just the last name.

Comment: True.  Depends on the context.  `getAbsolutePath` is the better general case.  Anyway, they will both at least be consistent across platforms.